# Better png for iexplorer 6 with fireworks instead of pngfix?

Tags: internet-explorer, png, transparency

I have made some screenshots of my website, and in internet explorer 6 my website looks crappy (see screenshot)

I have heard something about a PNG fix, is a PNG fix the way to solve the crappy look?

[Crappy look http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/e9/e91c994747851f0661ebc17d33e83201.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/e9/e91c994747851f0661ebc17d33e83201.png)

Do you think this could be helpfull for me?

[Better? http://howbigcanyouthink.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/png_image_display_in_ie6.png](http://howbigcanyouthink.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/png_image_display_in_ie6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use 24-bit opacity in PNG files, you have to use a PNG-FIX for Internet Explorer 6 - there is no way around it.

I strongly suggest using http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/ - this is currently the best working PNG-FIX out there.